# Number Keep Changing

Tags: javascript

I want to change the number by chooesing 6 numbers from 49 numbers, so first I declared a div and have six span in it to contain a number.

And I want to change it by getElementByTagName to assign a new number combined with setInterval to make it always changing but it doesn't work.

Where is my wrong place?

Thx.

```
function computeRandom(){

var value = new Array(49);//declare array


    for ( i = 0; i < 49; i++ )//initial array_value
        value[i] = i+1;



    for ( i = 0 ;i < 100; i++ ) {//random arrange
        x = parseInt(Math.random()*49);
        y = parseInt(Math.random()*49);
        tmp = value[x];
        value[x] = value[y];
        value[y] = tmp;     
    }


var color = new Array(49);

    for ( i = 0; i < 49; i++ )//store color
        color[i] = "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random()*255) + ")";      

    var value_tmp = new Array(6);

    for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        value_tmp[i] = value[i];

    document.write("<div style = \"text-align:center;\" >");//center the text by div

        for( i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            document.write("<span  style = \"font-size: 2.5em; display:inline-block; text-align:center; width: 1.5em; background: white; color: " + color[i] + " \" > " 
            + value_tmp[i] + "</span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp");

    var spanArray = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

    setInterval("keepMove(value,spanArray)",10);
    }

function keepMove(val,sp){  

var index = parseInt(Math.random()*43);//set a increment to avoid repeatition

for( i = 0; i < sp.length; i++){
    sp[i].innerHTML = val[i+index];
    document.write(sp[i].innerHTML+"  ");
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#bg {
background: grey;
opacity: 0.8;
}


#hl {
text-align: center;
color: white;
}
```

HTML:
sorry I　don't know how to post the HTML?
http://codepad.org/IrSOsjg7

I have tried the commentor's advice but still not work but thx for your help!
I very appreciate it!

Comment: does the browser give you any errors?

Comment: I believe a better way to get the random numbers is Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)

Comment: A number keep incrementing and a message :Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined

Comment: Can I ask what is the difference between parseInt(Math.random()*255) and Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is `setInterval("keepMove(value,spanArray)",10)`

when you pass a string as the first parameter of `setInterval`, it's like  `eval` that string, and the code will run in global environment, because there is no variable `value` and `spanArray` in the global environment, the code will not run correctly.

For example:

```
function foo(x, y) {
    alert(x + " " + y);
}

function bar() {
    var x = 100, y = 200;

    setInterval("foo(x, y)", 1000);
}

bar();
```

this will get the error `x is not defined`

You can try:

```
setInterval(function(){
    keepMove(value, spanArray);
}, 10);
```

​

Comment: I appreciate it and have learned a lesson, there is no error now. But after I post it, the whole page come to only left a number? I cannot understand why?

Comment: @Liang-YuPan I've make a demo with your codes, and it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkfhf/  you should remove `document.write` in `keepMove`, but I think it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the way you use the setInterval. You should use a closure to be able to access the value and spanArray vars.

```
setInterval(function(value, spanArray) { 
        return function() {
            keepMove(value,spanArray)
        }
    }(value, spanArray),10);
}
```

That's because setTimeout will be executed on the global context, and from there you can't access those private vars.